# Flag each record by comparing two variables in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, binary-data

How do I create a new binary variable that compares two other binary variables in an existing data frame?

For the data frame "dframe":

```
    ID       FlagA  FlagB
1   28602363    1    0
2   28605734    0    1
3   28608629    1    0
4   28611734    1    0
5   28619822    NA   0
6   28622689    1    1
7   28650295    NA   1
8   28650378    0    1
9   28651602    1    1
10  28656060    1    0
```

I tried to create the column "FlagAB", which would be 1 if FlagA=1 and FlagB=0, and 0 for any other combination, like this:

```
    ID          FlagA   FlagB   FlagAB
1   28602363    1       0       1
2   28605734    0       1       0
3   28608629    1       0       1
4   28611734.71 1       0       1
5   28619822    NA      0       0
6   28622689.71 1       1       0
7   28650295    NA      1       0
8   28650378    0       1       0
9   28651602    1       1       0
10  28656060    1       0       0
```

I tried a few variations of the following with no luck. This one populates all rows of FlagAB with "0"

```
dframe$FlagAB <- ifelse((dframe$FlagA=="1")&(dframe$FlagB=="0"),1,0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df$FlagAB <- ifelse(df$FlagA == 1 & !is.na(df$FlagA) & df$FlagB == 0, 1, 0)
df

         ID FlagA FlagB FlagAB
1  28602363     1     0      1
2  28605734     0     1      0
3  28608629     1     0      1
4  28611734     1     0      1
5  28619822    NA     0      0
6  28622689     1     1      0
7  28650295    NA     1      0
8  28650378     0     1      0
9  28651602     1     1      0
10 28656060     1     0      1
```

*EDIT*

As noted below, you actually don't need to use `ifelse` because the result is a logical vector.

```
as.numeric(df$FlagA == 1 & !is.na(df$FlagA) & df$FlagB == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to combine the two columns before comparing to the condition, so we don't have to care about the NAs because they will return a FALSE anyway.

```
x$FlagAB <- (paste(x$FlagA, x$FlagB) == paste(1,0))*1
```

Output:

```
         ID FlagA FlagB FlagAB
1  28602363     1     0      1
2  28605734     0     1      0
3  28608629     1     0      1
4  28611734     1     0      1
5  28619822    NA     0      0
6  28622689     1     1      0
7  28650295    NA     1      0
8  28650378     0     1      0
9  28651602     1     1      0
10 28656060     1     0      1
```

Other option is to create the column and then replace the NAs with zeroes:

```
x$FlagAB <- with(x, FlagA == 1 & FlagB == 0)*1
x$FlagAB[is.na(x$FlagAB)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also try this:

```
df$FlagAB <- 1*(df$FlagA & !df$FlagB & !is.na(df$FlagA))
> df
#         ID FlagA FlagB FlagAB
#1  28602363     1     0      1
#2  28605734     0     1      0
#3  28608629     1     0      1
#4  28611734     1     0      1
#5  28619822    NA     0      0
#6  28622689     1     1      0
#7  28650295    NA     1      0
#8  28650378     0     1      0
#9  28651602     1     1      0
#10 28656060     1     0      1
```

The expression in the bracket returns a logical vector, i.e., a vector with values TRUE/FALSE for each row the dataframe. By connecting the individual expressions with the logical AND operator `&`, we obtain a result that is only `TRUE` if

- FlagA is not equal to zero and
- FlagB is equal to zero and
- FlagA is not `NA`

In all other cases the result is `FALSE`.

The multiplication of the resulting logical vector with 1 has the same effect as the function `as.numeric()` in this case: the entries `FALSE` and `TRUE` are coerced into the numerical values `0` and `1`, respectively.

Finally, the result is stored in a new column named `FlagAB` in the dataframe.

**data**

```
 df <- structure(list(ID = c(28602363L, 28605734L, 28608629L, 28611734L, 
        28619822L, 28622689L, 28650295L, 28650378L, 28651602L, 28656060L), 
        FlagA = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L), FlagB = c(0L, 
        1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), 
        .Names = c("ID", "FlagA", "FlagB"), class = "data.frame", 
        row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```